# If Else statement in Woocommerce template page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I'm trying to write an if else statement for a Woocommerce template page that does this:

if category is not a subcategory then:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );
```

else show this:

```
<h3>
    <?php
        echo $category->name;

        if ( $category->count > 0 )
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
    ?>
</h3>
```

So far I have a very primitive function that is no where near what the end product will be.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the primitive function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following one:

```
$children = get_categories(array('child_of' => $category->term_id,'hide_empty' => 0));
if (count($children) < 1){
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );
}else{
?>
<h3>
<?php
    echo $category->name;

    if ( $category->count > 0 )
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
?>
</h3> <?php
}
```

Comment: Hey Pradeep, thank you so much for your reply! I actually already got this answered and I forgot to close the question but I very much appreciate your reply!